# Angular set ng-checked for specific child onclick

Tags: html, angularjs, input

If someone clicks on the link the child input element should get the attribute ng-checked = "true" and if he clicks again it should be set false.

I already managed to implement this behaviour but the problem is that i have multiple checkbox probably around 20 and i do not want to set a unique variable for all of those

```
<a href="" ng-click="setSelect()">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="someModel" ng-checked= "selectStatus">
           text
        </label>
    </div>
</a>
```

and the according setSelect method

```
$scope.toggleSelect = true;

$scope.setSelect = function () {
  if ($scope.toggleSelect){
    $scope.selectStatus = true;
    $scope.toggleSelect = false;
  } else {
    $scope.selectStatus = false;
    $scope.toggleSelect = true;
  }
};
```

is it possible to do this without jquery and in an easy way?

Comment: Where are the 20 checkboxes coming from? Are they in an ng-repeat you can use the array for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer you to render all of this textboxes using `ng-repeat` directive. So you don't need to worry about how much text boxes come. For doing this you need to add data of all the textboxes in well formatted JSON. You could also get rid of `setSelect` method by this approach.

And you shouldn't use `ng-checked` in any case because it doesn't set `ng-model` value it only do check/uncheck of checkbox, you will have `ng-click="item.someModel= !item.someModel"` which will do check and unchecking of check box.

**Markup**

```
<a href="" ng-click="item.someModel= !item.someModel">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.someModel">
           text
        </label>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: @glmodon Glad to help you, Thanks..don't forget to do upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

Where do you use jQuery in your code? The simplest solution is to negate the state of selectStatus.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="selectStatus != selectStatus">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="someModel" ng-checked= "selectStatus">
           text
        </label>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the approach of pankajparkar worked best for me!